# Nativescript Angular NativeScriptUIDataForm: Editors don't work

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

Dear stackoverflow comunity!

I am working on a nativescript angular project and I am trying to use the NativescriptUIDataform plugin. The installation and implementation did work. I get a generated form by NativescriptUIDataform.

package.json:

```json
"nativescript-ui-dataform": "^3.7.0",
```

app.module.ts:

```ts
import { NativeScriptUIDataFormModule } from "nativescript-ui-dataform/angular";
...
@NgModule({
   ...
   imports: [
   ...
       NativeScriptUIDataFormModule
   ...
```

My newEntry.component.ts looks like this:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { Entry } from "./entry";

@Component({
    selector: "newEntry",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./newEntry.component.html"
})
export class NewEntryComponent implements OnInit {
    private _entry: Entry;

    constructor(private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions) {

    }

    get entry(): Entry {
        return this._entry;
    }

    set entry(value: Entry) {
        this._entry = value;
    }

    public goBack() {
        this.routerExtensions.backToPreviousPage();
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

And in my newEntry.component.html I have following:

```html
<RadDataForm [source]="entry" tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton></RadDataForm>
```

To that point no problems appear. An automaticaly generated form appears in the app. But when I try to use the HTML Editors nothing changes only the automaticly generated form appears. Do I have to implement another module? What did I do wrong using the editors?

My newEntry.component.html with editors looks like this:

```html
<RadDataForm [source]="entry" tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton>
    <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="date" displayName="Date" index="0"></TKEntityProperty>
    <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="credit" displayName="Creditaccount" index="1" valuesProvider="something, something">
        <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Picker"></TKPropertyEditor>
    </TKEntityProperty>
    <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="debit" displayName="Debitaccount" index="2" valuesProvider="something, something">
        <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Picker"></TKPropertyEditor>
    </TKEntityProperty>
    <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="value" displayName="Value" index="3" type="number"></TKEntityProperty>
    <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="description" displayName="Description" index="4"></TKEntityProperty>
</RadDataForm>
```

Thank you for your answer in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are loading a module that don't have all the directives.

```
app-routing-module.ts
...
{ path: "newEntry", loadChildren: "~/app/newEntry/newEntry.module#NewEntryModule" }
...
```

Try to import `NativeScriptUIDataFormModule` into the module that declares NewEntryComponent (newEntry.module.ts) instead of `app.module.ts`

Cheers